# What to use instead of "smallest" in these contexts?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms, comparative

These are what I've found, so feel free to add to it.
First sentence:

> It was the smallest/lowest/least significant/ value among all three categories in 1990.

The second sentence:

> It reached the smallest/minimum value of X over the period.

or:

> It reached as low as X over the period.

or:

> It minimized at X over the period.

Comment: The last one is odd.

Comment: None of them are strictly wrong or right. They call can be wrong or right based on what exactly you're saying is happening and what X is. What is X?

Comment: "It reached a minimum value of X during the period" or possibly "During the period it reached / registered a minimum value of X"

Comment: @PeterJennings Why "a minimum"?

Comment: @AES Just a suggestion , an alternative word. I was thinking in terms of a graph of the data - the smallest value would be called the minimum. The daily noon temperature for the month of March for example. *During March the daily noon temperature registered a minimum of 4 degrees on the 14th.* There are better ways of saying this.